# Extracting selected data from a text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, text-files, extract

Now I am working on extracting information from a text file in Ruby.
Then how can I extract just the number '0.6748984055823062' from the following text file?

```
{
  "sentiment_analysis": [
    {
      "positive": [
        {
          "sentiment": "Popular",
          "topic": "games",
          "score": 0.6748984055823062,
          "original_text": "Popular games",
          "original_length": 13,
          "normalized_text": "Popular games",
          "normalized_length": 13,
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "sentiment": "engaging",
          "topic": "pop culture-inspired games",
          "score": 0.6280145725181376,
          "original_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "original_length": 35,
          "normalized_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "normalized_length": 35,
          "offset": 370
        },
```

What I have tried is that I could read a file and print it line by line by the following code.

```
counter = 1
file = File.new("Code.org", "r")
while (line = file.gets)
  puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
  counter = counter + 1
end
file.close
```

I want to set the number to a variable so that I can process it.

Comment: I found out how to read a file and print it line by line. But the extracting is hard for me.

Comment: This looks like part of a JSON file. Have you tried [`JSON.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON)?

Comment: Oh, you may be right. The file format looks like JSON. I will try JSON.parse.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking, it's important that the code and data allow testing. The JSON sample isn't syntactically correct, forcing us to fix it just to help you. That wastes our time so help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script which extracts just the score you want.

Two things to keep in mind :

- the score you're looking for might not be the first one
- the data is a mix of Arrays and Hashes

```
json_string = %q${
  "sentiment_analysis": [
    {
      "positive": [
        {
          "sentiment": "Popular",
          "topic": "games",
          "score": 0.6748984055823062,
          "original_text": "Popular games",
          "original_length": 13,
          "normalized_text": "Popular games",
          "normalized_length": 13,
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "sentiment": "engaging",
          "topic": "pop culture-inspired games",
          "score": 0.6280145725181376,
          "original_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "original_length": 35,
          "normalized_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "normalized_length": 35,
          "offset": 370
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
$

require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(json_string)

puts json["sentiment_analysis"].first["positive"].first["score"]
#=> 0.6748984055823062
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the data is a JSON string.  In that case you can parse it and do something like the following:

```
require 'json'

file = File.read('Code.org')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)

score = data_hash['score']
```

Comment: Would you take a look at the file again? The text is nested, so it looks I can't use the code you suggested.

Comment: The number you're asking for doesn't appear in the sample you present, but it should be possible to navigate to it or iterate over all possible matches using `[]`.

Comment: Ruby doesn't use backticks for string literals. Either single or double quotes are acceptable and would be used as the parameter for a `require` statement. backticks are used to execute a command in a sub-shell and return the STDOUT. Also, `data_hash['score']` won't return what the OP wants, instead it'd return 'nil'. I'd recommend you try running your code.

Comment: @theTinMan yeah, that was totally a mistype on my part. Thanks for fixing it