# Parsing from a JSON file in Ruby and Extract numbers from Nested Hashes

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

Now I am working on extracting information from a JSON file in Ruby. Then how can I extract just the numbers next to the word 'score' from the following text file? For example, I want to get 0.6748984055823062, 0.6280145725181376 on and on.

```
{
  "sentiment_analysis": [
    {
      "positive": [
        {
          "sentiment": "Popular",
          "topic": "games",
          "score": 0.6748984055823062,
          "original_text": "Popular games",
          "original_length": 13,
          "normalized_text": "Popular games",
          "normalized_length": 13,
          "offset": 0
        },
        {
          "sentiment": "engaging",
          "topic": "pop culture-inspired games",
          "score": 0.6280145725181376,
          "original_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "original_length": 35,
          "normalized_text": "engaging pop culture-inspired games",
          "normalized_length": 35,
          "offset": 370
        },
     "negative": [
    {
      "sentiment": "get sucked into",
      "topic": "the idea of planning",
      "score": -0.7923352042939829,
      "original_text": "Students get sucked into the idea of planning",
      "original_length": 45,
      "normalized_text": "Students get sucked into the idea of planning",
      "normalized_length": 45,
      "offset": 342
    },
    {
      "sentiment": "be daunted",
      "topic": null,
      "score": -0.5734506634410159,
      "original_text": "initially be daunted",
      "original_length": 20,
      "normalized_text": "initially be daunted",
      "normalized_length": 20,
      "offset": 2104
    },
```

What I have tried is that I could read a file and set the text file to a hash variable using the JSON method.

```
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(json_string)
```

Comment: This is based on http://stackoverflow.com/q/40936239/128421, in which the selected answer explains how to do it for the first element in the array. Based on that, what have you tried? You need to figure out how to iterate over an array. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to collect the reviews.

```
reviews = json['sentiment_analysis'][0]
positive_reviews = reviews['positive']
negative_reviews = reviews['negative']

positive_reviews.map { |review| review['score'] }
=> [0.6748984055823062, 0.6280145725181376]

negative_reviews.map { |review| review['score'] }
=> [-0.7923352042939829, -0.5734506634410159]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It greatly worked as you suggested. Thank you! Could you explain what the [0] means in json['sentiment_analysis'][0]['positive']?

Comment: `json['sentiment_analysis']` holds an array of objects and the data you're looking for is present in the first index. So, you use [0] to index into the object and then parse the `"positives"` object. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok I see. Then could you take a look at the text file above again? I added "negatives" more to the text. In this case, should I use  json['sentiment_analysis'][0]['negative'] or json['sentiment_analysis'][1]['negative']?

Comment: @SookieJ  Updated the answer. Have a look and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 75):

Using the `JSON` class:

Importing a file:

```
require "json"
file = File.open "/path/to/your/file.json"
data = JSON.load file
```

Optionally, you can close it now:

```
file.close
```

The file looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "Facebook",
  "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
  "posts": [
    "lemon-car",
    "dead-memes"
  ]
}
```

The file is now able to be read like this:

```
data["title"]
=> "Facebook"
data.keys
=> ["title", "url", "posts"]
data['posts']
=> ["lemon-car", "dead-memes"]
data["url"]
=> "https://www.facebook.com"
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: You should not use `File.read`, which loads the whole file in memory.  `File.open` works fine with `JSON.load`.

Comment: If this is the option you choose, don't forget to `file.close`!

Comment: You need `JSON.load` instead of `JSON.parse`, parse only takes a string, load will take a file.  You also need `require "json"` instead of include.

Answer (score 28):

Parse Data from File:

`data_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json'))`

Then just map over the data!

```
reviews = data_hash['sentiment_analysis'].first
reviews.map do |sentiment, reviews|
  puts "#{sentiment} #{reviews.map { |review| review['score'] }}"
end
```

I think this is the simplest answer.

Comment: yeah but then you can don't know how to read it apart from just trying it out in IRB

Comment: @MichalŠtein - this answer seems quite simple, and handles closing the file (your answer doesn't) - please explain your concern with this answer?

Comment: The answer does not say what to do after you load it. And I am gonna add the file closing, that's a great idea.